# Mousewheel issue in THREE.js Editor

Tags: javascript, three.js, editor, mouse, mousewheel

I am trying to create a simple scene in THREE.js Editor.

I use the built in Script editor and all the other control functions work properly except the mousewheel ( tried mousedown, mousemove etc. ). I tried to add a listener to the mouse wheel too without success.
This is how I am trying to test if it works:

```
function mousewheel( event ){ console.log("mouseScrolled") }
```

I know that I can just publish and edit that .js, maybe even add the TrackBallControls.js, but for the usability of the Editor it would be great if this could work.

thanks in advance!

Comment: mouseweel works only in Chrome. Witch browser you are using?

Comment: I was just about to post an answer to my own question :) I am using Chrome. and now it seems to work for some reason, I am writing the exact same code.... It also works when im declaring an eventListener :p.

Comment: Sill I am curious if there is a workaround to mouseWheel usage for other browsers, any ideas?

Comment: You can see here for some informations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseWheelEvent

Comment: thx, I ll check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mousewheel function was for some reason not working in the THREE.js Editor, and without any explanation now it does work.